# Laravel framework - workbench

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

What is a workbench in the laravel framework? (I am using version 4 - beta)

How is a workbench used and what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a tool for creating php packages; with special functionality to aid in creating packages that can easily be used within a Laravel 4 project.

Comment: So I could use it to create a package for my app and the package would be made so that it was independent of my app and therefore would be available for use in any application?

Comment: Correct. [Package Development](http://four.laravel.com/docs/packages) has more information on developing packages

Comment: Okay. Will take a look. Thanks for the link. Was getting nowhere with Google.